Adding custom arithmetic aggregation in a grouped dataframe along with .agg functions in pandas/python
I am an R user and now learning Python too from scratch.
I have this sample data frame.

I want to group the df by Name and Fiscal_year, then add the sum of sale and also the monthly average sale of each product for each fiscal year.
The mean function divides the sum of sale by the count of day however I want sum of sale divide by distinct count of month.
Below is the output I am looking for.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thank You.
I tried the below method
df1 = df.groupby(['Name', 'Fiscal_Year'], as_index=False)
df1 = df1.agg(Total_Sales = ('sale', 'sum'), Mavg = ('Sale', 'mean'))
df

I also tried multple ways of arithmetic like:
df['Mavg] = df['sale'].sum()/df['month].nunique()
this can may be work individually but I cant apply it on a grouping.
Reproducible input:
df = pd.DataFrame( {
    'Name': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    'day': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    'month': ['Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'Apr', 'May', 'May', 'May', 'May'],
    'Fiscal_Year': ['FY2023-24', 'FY2023-24', 'FY2024-25', 'FY2024-25', 'FY2023-24', 'FY2023-24', 'FY2024-25', 'FY2024-25',
                    'FY2023-24', 'FY2023-24', 'FY2024-25', 'FY2024-25', 'FY2023-24', 'FY2023-24', 'FY2024-25', 'FY2024-25'],
    'sale': [100, 222, 333, 444, 200, 111, 555, 366, 666, 777, 300, 345, 756, 896, 452, 365]
})


Please add your sample df and output df as text, not as images.

You need two groupby.
First aggregate including the month to compute the monthly sum, then perform your custom aggregation:
out = (df
   .groupby(['Name', 'month', 'Fiscal_Year'], as_index=False)['sale'].sum()
   .groupby(['Name', 'Fiscal_Year'], as_index=False)
   .agg(Total_Sales = ('sale', 'sum'), Mavg = ('sale', 'mean'))
)

Output:
  Name Fiscal_Year  Total_Sales    Mavg
0    a   FY2023-24          633   316.5
1    a   FY2024-25         1698   849.0
2    b   FY2023-24         3095  1547.5
3    b   FY2024-25         1462   731.0

